# Allow iOS user to have your app ignore Do Not Disturb mode

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I'm almost certain the answer to this question is 'no', but if it's not, it's worth asking.

My app allows a user to track their anxiety at an interval (e.g. every 15 minutes) while they work.  It schedules a local notification to alert the user that 15 minutes is up, and when they touch the notification and open the app, it prompts them to rate their anxiety.

One thing that causes me anxiety when I'm already super stressed is text messages, so I sometimes turn on Do Not Disturb mode while I work.  However, I'd still like to hear my app's notifications, and I think this would be a fairly common use case for my user base.  Is there a way for my app to request permission to ignore Do Not Disturb, like there is for the app to request permissions to send notifications in the first place?  The Apple Clock app can make noise, but I'm guessing they have access to an SDK with greater capabilities.

If the answer is no, like I assume it is, is there a clever work-around for this?  (Manually turning off notifications for every other app on my phone, and then turning them back on when I'm done working is not worth it to me.)

Comment: What you could do is make that system SMS-based and have the User make the number you're using a VIP.

Comment: Wow, that is clever.  A little bit over-engineered, but definitely clever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately no, there is no opt out for Do Not Disturb and any clever workarounds that may exist are likely to get rejected as messing with notifications breaks the guidelines:

> 2.5.3 Apps that ... disrupt the normal operation of the operating system ... including Push Notifications ... will be rejected.
>
> https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#software-requirements

You are left with clunky workarounds, like getting your users to manually create their own clock alarms.